# Incorrect output in small program. Why is this String variable not doing what I want it to?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

This program should take a String, check if each letter is a vowel and change the vowels into underscores. For example, if I enter `some` it should output `s_m_`. This is a simple programming exercise that I feel like I should be able to do. However I am genuinely stumped and can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

I have declared an array to keep the vowels, a `newStr` variable which will contain the updated string ,and I'm looping through the string, comparing each letter using `charAt()` to check if it's in the `vowels` array. If it is, I add `_` to the updated String, and I keep the original letter if it's not. The final output is wrong, what am I doing wrong?

```
char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
String newStr = "";

for (int x = 0; x < str.length(); x++) {
    char letter = str.charAt(x);

    for (int j = 0; j < vowels.length; j++) {
        if (letter == vowels[j]) {
            newStr = newStr + '_';
            break;
        } else {
            newStr = newStr + letter;
            break;
        }
    }
}

out.println(newStr);
```

Comment: Looks like your inner loop (`j`) executes a `break` no matter what after the first test.  So it will only check for an `a` and nothing more.

Comment: `newStr = newStr + letter;` should be done once if the letter doesn't match any vowel (i.e after the for loop)

Comment: Stepping through your code in your IDE is ideal for solving small problems like this.

Comment: I think the best idea would be to introduce a method like `isVowel()` that returns true or false if its char parameter is a vowel.  That would help clean up the code a lot and make that `if` test easier to understand (and fix).

Comment: Not really useful, but you forgot the 'y' vowel.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to achieve this. Why do you need 2 for-loops? Also did you try debugging your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the issue is within your nested "for-loop". I say this in quotes because it never actually loops. The first iteration `j=0` immediately breaks the loop since either your letter is equal to `a` with `(letter == vowels[0])` or not. In either case you do a `break;` and append the character. This means your loop can be reduced to a simple `if-else` that checks if the letter is an `a` and replaces it with `_` or keeps it.

To fix this issue you need to use a different approach. You can create a String of vowels such as "aeiouAEIOU" and use [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) to test whether the selected character is a vowel.

```
public static String omitVowels(String input) {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        if (vowels.indexOf(c) >= 0) // is vowel if index not negative
            out.append('_');
        else
            out.append(c);
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

`indexOf(char)` will return `-1` if the provided character is not part of the string, else it will return the specific index. We can use this property to test whether the character is a vowel or not.

**Examples**

`omitVowels("hello world")` -> `"h_ll_ w_rld"`

`omitVowels("aeiou")` -> `"_____"`

`omitVowels("TESTing")` -> `"T_ST_ng"`

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple. Just iterate over each character of the given string and replace with `_` in case of it is vowel.

#### Use StringBuilder

Be ware of using `String`. This is **immutable** in java, therefore to build final string, you should use `StringBuilder`.

```
public static String replaceVowel(String str) {
    final IntPredicate isVowel = ch -> ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u';
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        boolean vowel = isVowel.test(Character.toLowerCase(ch));
        buf.append(vowel ? '_' : ch);
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

---

#### Use RegularExpression

As alternative, you can use *Regular Expression* with `replaceAll()` method of the `String` class.

```
private static final Pattern VOWEL = Pattern.compile("[aeiou]");

public static String replaceVowel(String str) {
    return VOWEL.matcher(str).replaceAll("_");
}
```

This is also correct, because in the background, `replaceAll()` uses `StringBUilder`.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int x = 0; x < str.length(); x++) {
 char letter = str.charAt(x);
 boolean toReplace = false;
 for (int j = 0; j < vowels.length; j++) {
    if (letter == vowels[j]) {
        toReplace = true;
        break;
    }
 }
 if (toReplace) {
    newStr = newStr + "_";
 } else {
    newStr = newStr + letter;
 }
}
```

Comment: Or simply `newStr = str.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "_");` but I guess you're trying to do this as an exercise and are not looking for a one line solution :-). In such case I strongly recommend using StringBuilder to create the new String. Just for the sake of your studies :-). Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, Cannot agree more!
In production is the best idea to use StringBuilder.

Comment: Be ware of **string concatenation in loop**!